# Apache: Use a PHP script as a handler for security screening before continuing to original file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can I use a php script as handler for loading a document in a directory?

My .htaccess (in "/path/to/") would say:

```
AddHandler handler .png
Action handler /path/to/security.php
```

And the security.php would do what it was supposed to do, e.g. check databases etc and then continue on to the original file that was loaded. For example:

User attempts to load '/path/to/awesome_picture.png'. The server checks .htaccess and sees the handler. It executes the handler. Following this, the PHP script would redirect to the original file if it saw fit. So user would eventually receive the picture but would undergo checks along the way.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would not use a redirect in this scenario, but rather would need to serve up the content via PHP (with appropriate headers of course). A redirect to `*.png` would just trigger the handler again and get you in a circular loop.

Comment: I have just discovered this now, as you posted that. I shall try serving it through the PHP instead.

Comment: @MikeBrant After searching this as well, how can I generically display a file of any type (html/image/txt etc) while simulating as if it was displayed directly, as opposed to being displayed through a PHP script?

Comment: Just Goggle something like "PHP file download" or search through SO for examples.  The basic concept is that the PHP script has to read information about the file and server up appropriate repsonse headers such that the browser recognizes the file type, size, etc. that is being server up.  Then you output the file to the browser.

Comment: @MikeBrant Ahh I was never aware of this realm of PHP. Is [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2513) what you meant?

Comment: Yes. That is a good basic example. Though that specific example would be for a file transfer type of download.  Typically, you would serve up the appropriate image content type header rather than octet-stream.

Comment: Yes, I just meant that was how headers were supposed to be used. But thanks for the clarification. I have now got a working system that has been able to output all the files that I currently need it to to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#action) it seems that you can, since the second example matches the config you have written.

But it seems a better idea (to me at least) to use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^(.*\.png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/security.php?img=$1 [NC,L]
```

Then you can reference the requested file in your PHP script via `$_GET['img']`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I read over the link you suggested but apparently this line: 'It sends the URL and file path of the requested document using the standard CGI PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED environment variables.' escaped my view. Thank you also for your other suggestion but I am trying to minimise .htacces coding involved and although it would only require adding a couple of characters I would like to add more extensions in the future and handlers just seem easier for me.

Comment: To get it to work using `AddHandler` and `Action` I had to use `Action handler /path/to/security.php?q=` so that the path to the requested file is passed as a param.  Otherwise PHP simply tries to parse the PNG file as a script file input. Not sure if that's just a quirk of my setup or not...

Comment: I don't appear to have that issue... Using `AddHandler handler .png
Action handler /LoginTest/security.php` in my security.php I can retrieve the file that was requested using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to pass that along in case you had a similar problem. Perhaps it happens because I'm running PHP via FCGI so the request itself is passed to `php-cgi` and somewhere things get confused. Anyway, glad you got it working the way you want!